# How to sync windows server folders with a AIX server using script?

Tags: windows, shell, scripting, batch-file, aix

Everyday I would like to sync the files and folders in the windows server with AIX server and vice versa. Does anyone suggest me, How I can write a shell or bat script to achieve this?

Comment: also asked on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/q/327169/30957)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest rsync over ssh.  This would make your windows server the "client" which initiates all transactions.  You'll have to install both rsync and ssh on your windows server, but this makes things so easy that it's worth the effort.  I'm not sure if rsync is required on the server, and, if it is, whether it's available from IBM for AIX or if you have to do that yourself.  Again, the code is already written, so what's left is the "easy" bit.